# Stream PowerPoint as video

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, microsoft-powerpoint

Are there any tools available to convert PowerPoint presentation into an video file and then broadcast it live in sync with someone changing slides manually? The goal is to broadcast presentation live to many clients at once..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of PowerPoint 2010, there is a feature called [Broadcast Slide Show](https://web.archive.org/web/20100608094712/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/powerpoint/archive/2009/10/09/introducing-broadcast-slide-show.aspx). This feature (accessed via the Slide Show tab on the ribbon) will give you a link that you can send out to anyone who should be watching. When they open the link in their browser, they will see the slide show synchronized with the presenter's view (so when the presenter changes slides they will see the slide change too). It's completely free, and even works on mobile devices such as Droids!

Comment: Thanks - that's what we're using after all. Sorry for delaying the comment/approval for this long...

Answer (score 0):

Popular streaming video site [Ustream](http://www.ustream.tv/) supports doing this through [third-party software](http://helpcenter.ustream.tv/content/adding-graphics-and-other-effects). The 3rd party software for Macs is free, but for Windows costs.

Comment: Looks interesting - but ustream is a hosted service only, right? I.e. I cannot install it on my own machine..

Comment: That is correct. If I find any which aren't, I'll edit the post, but I can't think of any at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answers to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/78515/is-there-any-software-that-can-capture-the-screen-and-turn-it-into-a-fake-webcam) question, you can capture Powerpoint (or any other application) and use it as a camera input to whatever streaming software you like to use.