# Switch camera to screen while switching tabs in browser

Tags: windows, video, google-chrome-extensions, webcam, conferencing

I am a student, who has started using online libraries (based on the concept of social accountability). A library in Indian/UPSC context is a bit different from a standard library elsewhere as it doesn't contain books and is simply a place where people preparing for government/academic exams get together and study individually/ sometimes discuss topics.(not more than 2 people generally, there are no formal 'discussions' as such)

However, I am faced with a problem as I sometimes switch to another tab, other than where the video conferencing is held, and I browse internet(something that I am not supposed to do while studying). So, I would be glad if someone could suggest a way to auto switch the camera video to screen video (what's going on the screen) whenever I switch to another tab/ minimize chrome, so that others can know what I am doing presently is related to study or not.

The platform used on the library site is based on 'jitsi', an obscure open source free video conferencing platform, so there's no option for switching over to screen recording.

In case automatic switching cannot be done with some simple software/chrome extension(or requires custom code to execute), then I would simply like to know how to screen record in a video conferencing that doesn't explicitly have the screen display button/function. It should be possible as you simply have to manipulate the webcam hardware driver/interface to display the screen instead of taking the camera hardware feed.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You want to record/stream what is going on on your screen to a conferencing app, presumably when you are not a presented on the conference?

Comment: This question has been closed, but it asks pretty much precisely the same question you have, it just asks it in a way SuperUser doesn't allow. It still has answers though: https://superuser.com/questions/78515/is-there-any-software-that-can-capture-the-screen-and-turn-it-into-a-fake-webcam

Comment: @music2myear Yes, when I am not a presenter, but my video is on and visible to others. Thank you for the helpful link, it does look related. I will try the solutions and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks, the most upvoted answer in the link that you have provided, works rather simply. Now, only if someone could give a heads up on how to implement tab automation, it would be great.